# YII: How to update ajax data on page load?

Tags: php, ajax, drop-down-menu, yii

I have a dropdownlist which updates an ajax field. All works fine but the ajax field does not get filled with data on page load. How can I force the ajax field update, on page load?

This is the dropdownlist in view:

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('category_selection_code', '', $cat_list_data, 
        array('style'=>'width:400px',
              'ajax' => 
                        array(
                            'type'=>'POST', 
                            'url'=>CController::createUrl('articles/GetContentFields'), 
                            'update'=>'#ExtraContentFields', 

                        )
            )
);
```

---

*UPDATE

I've found the solution which is working for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {category_selection_code: $('#category_selection_code').val()},
        url: '<?php echo CController::createUrl('articles/GetContentFields'); ?>',
        success: function(data){
                    $('#ExtraContentFields').html(data)
                }
    })
})
```

Controller for ajax processing **articles/GetContentFields** is waiting **category_selection_code** parameter in $_POST array. And we should to set it in the **data** section of ajax part:

data: {**category_selection_code**: $('#category_selection_code').val()},

---

Thnx all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you've done above is correct. Firstly, the fourth parameter to CHtml::dropdownList() function is an HTML options array. [See the function signature for CHtml::dropdownList()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail)

Put your AJAX call within

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 //Your call goes in here. 
});
```

Comment: it's correct, you can have `'ajax'` option in htmlOptions. Yii allows this through the [clientChange](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#clientChange-detail "http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#clientChange-detail") property/method.

Comment: If you found my answer useful, I'd appreciate a vote up! Thanks.

Comment: i was saying that you are **wrong** in doubting that the **fourth parameter(** `htmlOptions` **) can't have** `'ajax'` **option.**

Answer (score 1):

Fire change event worked for me.
Also, I found useful `CHtml::activeId(..)` method.

```
<?php
$cs = Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript(
  'update-brand-car-on-page-load',
  '$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#'.CHtml::activeId($model, 't_brand_car').'").change();
    });'
);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('input name["category_selection_code"]').change();
});
```